# $(pwd) at docker-in-docker volume mounts unexpected directory

Tags: docker, docker-volume, docker-in-docker

Example:

```
pavel@Z546:~/test/dind-volumes$ ls
test.txt
pavel@Z546:~/test/dind-volumes$ docker run -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v $(pwd):/app -w /app -it docker sh
/app # ls
test.txt
/app # pwd
/app
/app # docker run -v $(pwd):/app2 -w /app2 -it alpine sh
/app2 # ls
share       tomita-cfg
/app2 # pwd
/app2
```

Which location `-v $(pwd):/app2` mounts? It's not `~/test/dind-volumes` on host OS. `share` and `tomita-cfg` are folders from host OS, but path is exactly different, it's even not started from `~`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The directory that gets mounted into the new container is whatever is in the `/app` directory on the host.

This is *not* [Docker in Docker](https://hub.docker.com/_/docker/) as I understand the term to mean: you are not running a second copy of Docker inside a Docker container, you are merely making access to the host's Docker socket available inside a container.

In the scenario you show, when you are inside a container with the host's Docker socket mounted and run `docker run -v $(pwd):/app2 ...`, first the shell inside the container expands `$(pwd)` to `/app`, and then it sends a request to the Docker daemon to launch a container with `/app` bind-mounted to `/app2`.  From the Docken daemon's point of view, this is indistinguishable from running the same command on the host directly.

Comment: Thanks for explanation. Solved with using environment variables: `docker run -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v $(pwd):/app -w /app -e PATH_HOST=$(pwd) -it docker sh` and then `docker run -v ${PATH_HOST}:/app2 -w /app2 -it alpine sh`